# Using queryStringQuery and boolQuery for date range

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am using Java to run queries on ElasticSearch. I'm having difficulties running range queries using boolQuery() API and queryStringQuery as input. here's the code:

```
 QueryBuilder stringQuery = QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query);
 QueryBuilder finalQuery = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(stringQuery);
```

The data field for date has the following format:

```
"startedOn" : { "type" : "date", "format": "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS" }
```

and I am using queries like these:

```
StartedOn < 2020-06-29
StartedOn : [2020-06-20 TO 2020-06-25]
```

But none of them seem to return the correct results. Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Comment: don't use the QueryStringQuery for date fields, there is a Date query for that! https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: thanks Ian, I know about that, but I am exposing this as an API and I wanna have the input as simple as possible, and I want to avoid having to expose an API specific to date ranges, want to have just one query API that can handle all different cases, including date ranges.

Comment: See the date syntax here then: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_ranges

In this case, you probably don't need the bool query at all then.